# LiteSpeed VS OpenLiteSpeed

Tags: apache, web-services, litespeed

Due to information in [LiteSpeedTech site](https://www.litespeedtech.com/index.php/products/litespeed-web-server/editions) I didn't found any significant difference between community and enterprise edition. Is there a reason I use enterprise edition instead of community. 
I found some issue about Apache compatibility for community edition. Is this the only difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important difference between community version(OpenLiteSpeed) and LiteSpeed Enterprise is that OpenLiteSpeed will not autodetect an update to .htaccess. OpenLiteSpeed is most frequently used for individual sites that don't change often and it's suggested that you simply restart OpenLiteSpeed to load any new .htaccess file.

If you are in a situation where you need to frequently update, such as a shared hosting environment, then you'll want to use LiteSpeed Enterprise.

Now, if you scroll down the edition page a little bit, you can also find that OpenLiteSpeed support rewrite rules in .htaccess only and NOT support below items as well:

1. ESI
2. Prestashop and Magento lscache plugins
3. Brute force attack function
4. Advanced service for hosting server